# Java - Trying to print an index in a String Array Using get method

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing, getmethod

So i have a String array

```
private  String[] transmission = {"Drive", "Park", "Reverse"};
```

Here is my set method, I'm practicing my switch statement as I don't use it often.

```
public void setTransmission(String[] transmission) {
    System.out.println("To change the transmission, enter D for Drive,P for Park or R for reverse");
    switch (input.nextLine()) {
        case "D":
        case "d":
            System.out.println("The Car is currently in Drive.");
            transmission[0] = this.transmission[0];
            break;
        case "P":
        case "p":
            System.out.println("The Car is currently in Park.");
            transmission[1] = this.transmission[1];
            break;
        case "R":
        case "r":
            System.out.println("The Car is currently in Reverse");
            transmission[2] = this.transmission[2];
            break;

    }
```

Here is the real PROBLEM. In my getMethod it only prints the first index in the array:

```
 public String getTransmission()
    {
        return String.format("The car is currently in %s",transmission);
    }
```

How can i get it to print what the user entered? I know i could just use a string variable but i would prefer to use an array.

Comment: You should swap your assignments in your `setTransmission` method. I.e `this.transmission[0] = transmission[0];` and so on.

Comment: You could keep track of the index where the new transition was inserted and return `transmission[index]` at the getter.

Comment: @user3044002 You are probably looking for: `String.format("The car is currently in %s",Arrays.toString(transmission)))`

Comment: @ZouZou probably not, actually.

Comment: @DavidWallace Then I don't see what's the point of this `getTransmission` method. Should it return the content of the all array or not?

Comment: You will need to have some kind of field in your class that stores the current "gear", so that it can be returned.  You could either store it as the `String` value itself, or as an `int` indicating an index into the array.  Assign this field within the `setTransmission` method.

Comment: Your title is very confusing and does not seem to agree with the rest of your post. What **index** are you trying to print?

Comment: I want the getMethod to return an index of the array that the user input defined. In my setTransmission method you enter D for driver, P for park and R for reverse. If enter P for park and then call the getMethod after that it stills says drive

Comment: I fixed it, just made a variable int called gear and set it to values based on user input. Then in my getTransmission i used if(gear == 1) etc..

Comment: @user3044002 You could post that as a solution, for the benefit of the next person to have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this occurs in the same class, you would need the index as an internal state.

a possible implementation would be:

```
public class Car
{
    private final String[] transmission = { "Drive", "Park", "Reverse" };

    private final Scanner  input;

    private int            index;

    public Car( Scanner input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setTransmission()
    {
        System.out.println( "To change the transmission, enter D for Drive,P for Park or R for reverse" );
        switch ( input.nextLine() )
        {
        case "D":
        case "d":
            System.out.println( "The Car is currently in Drive." );
            index = 0;
            break;
        case "P":
        case "p":
            System.out.println( "The Car is currently in Park." );
            index = 1;
            break;
        case "R":
        case "r":
            System.out.println( "The Car is currently in Reverse" );
            index = 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    public String getTransmission()
    {
        return String.format( "The car is currently in %s", transmission[index] );
    }
}
```

It would help, if you could could add a little more context to your problem. Especially how you call your methods and where they reside.

A better design would probably be to create an enum for the transmission and separate the parsing from the data.

This would reduce the car to a data container without any logic:

```
public class Car
{
    public enum Transmission
    {
        Drive, Park, Reverse
    }

    private Transmission transmission;

    public void setTransmission( Transmission transmission )
    {
        this.transmission = transmission;
    }

    public String getTransmission()
    {
        return String.format( "The car is currently in %s", transmission );
    }
}
```

An application, that uses this Car class would the parse the transmission and set the typed Transmission in the car:

```
public class CarApplication
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try ( Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "To change the transmission, enter D for Drive,P for Park or R for reverse" );
            String answer = input.nextLine();
            Transmission transmission = parseTransmission( answer );

            Car car = new Car();

            car.setTransmission( transmission );

            System.out.println( car.getTransmission() );
        }
    }

    private static Transmission parseTransmission( String input )
    {
        switch ( input )
        {
        case "D":
        case "d":
            return Transmission.Drive;
        case "P":
        case "p":
            return Transmission.Park;
        case "R":
        case "r":
            return Transmission.Reverse;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "expected an input D,P,R but got: " + input );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please note, that `switch` for Strings was introduced only in Java 7. If you are using Java 6 and below, you have to use `if` statement